# Access AKS API from private IP range with api-server-authorized-ip-ranges enabled

Tags: azure-aks

I have a VM that hosts an Azure DevOps agent. The VM does not have a public IP. I can run deployments to AKS fine without api-server-authorized-ip-ranges using kubectl apply (getting a .kube config via az).

Once I add an authorised IP range I can no longer run deployments. I can't add a private IP range as I get this exception:

> --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges must be global non-reserved addresses or CIDRs

Due to various policies I am unable give my VM a public IP. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Did you figure out?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `api-server-authorized-ip-ranges` option with private IPs. The IPs must be public as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/api-server-authorized-ip-ranges#create-an-aks-cluster-with-api-server-authorized-ip-ranges-enabled), or alternatively you can create a [private AKS cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters)

Comment: There is no where in the document you provided is there a sentence saying "private IP address is not accepted". Carefully read the lines `These IP address ranges are usually address ranges used by your on-premises networks or public IPs` They use the word `usually` but no where have they mentioned only public IP addresses are accepted.